# Problems loading dlls from AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement in VS 2017

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I downloaded the NuGet package AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement from VS 2017 and I repeated the step few times as no dlls from this package were added to the bin folder. Anyway, I had all the other dlls that are integrated in an AWS Console Project like those for EC2, S3 and SimpleDB.
So I decided to do the same in VS 2015 and it turned out to be working as expected.
I was wondering what could be the reason for that? I am sure that I followed the same steps in both VS.

Comment: Hi, I executed the following command in the nuget console `Install-Package AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement -Version 3.3.15`...and checking the references for the project, it added the 2 following references  `AWSSDK.Core` and `AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement`

Comment: Yes, they are really added but that doesn't make it work unfortunately. What I have found as a difference is that in VS 2017 in AWS Console Project we no longer have "References" but "Dependancies" which are separated into "Assemblies" and "NuGet". The  new packages are added under NuGet and the path to them is not directly in the bin\Debug folder but in bin\Debug\net45 and probably somehow it is not finding them.